# Defining custom type vars -> Copying custom type defined array - Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I'd like to know if anyone could point me out to what would be the difference when using the two different copy approaches for array, which is defined as type.

I needed to make a function that would order the elements of integers in dynamic array, from either min to max or max to min. Therefore, I created a new type like this:

```
type IntArray = array of integer;
```

Then I defined a function to sort, with two directions, which are identified by integer passed, with parameter being 0 to sort towards minimum (max -> min) or 1 to sort towards max (min -> max).

```
function SortArray(ToSort: IntArray; Direction: integer): IntArray;
var count, i: integer;
Label Label1, Label2;
begin
count:=Length(ToSort);
if (Direction = 1) then
  begin
    Label1:
    for i := 0 to count-2 do
      begin
        if ToSort[i+1] > ToSort[i] then
          begin
            ToSort[i+1]  :=ToSort[i]   +ToSort[i+1];
            ToSort[i]    :=ToSort[i+1] -ToSort[i];
            ToSort[i+1]  :=ToSort[i+1] -ToSort[i];
            GoTo Label1;
          end;
      end;
  end
else
if (Direction = 0) then
  begin
    Label2:
    for i := 0 to count-2 do
      begin
        if ToSort[i+1] < ToSort[i] then
          begin
            ToSort[i+1]  :=ToSort[i]   +ToSort[i+1];
            ToSort[i]    :=ToSort[i+1] -ToSort[i];
            ToSort[i+1]  :=ToSort[i+1] -ToSort[i];
            GoTo Label2;
          end;
      end;
  end;

Result:=ToSort;
```

Now, this function works fine as it seems, however the result differs regarding how I define the arrays that are passed to the function call;

I have an OnClick event for a button, which gives two calls of the function:

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var a, b: IntArray;
  i: Integer;
begin
SetLength(a, 10);
SetLength(b, 10);

for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    a[i]:=Random(100);      
    b[i]:=a[i];             // Example 1;
  end;

// b:=a;                    // Example 2;

a:=SortArray(a, 1);
b:=SortArray(b, 0);

for i := 0 to 9 do
  begin
    Listbox1.Items.Add(InttoStr(a[i]));
    Listbox2.Items.Add(InttoStr(b[i]));
  end;
end;
```

Now the thing is, if I define array B the way it is provided with example 1, -> the function works fine. A is sorted towards maximum, while B is sorted towards minimum;

However, if I define array B the way it is provided with example 2, -> the function gives me the same result for both calls, both being arrays sorted towards maximum (as called in the first call).

Why does it make a difference how I define array b, and why shouldn't I copy it directly as var to var?
Doesn't seem to make much sense to me at this point...

Comment: This is explained in the documentation http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types#Dynamic_Arrays Start reading "if X and Y ..."

Comment: oh my, I see now, that was my first thought but wasn's making much sense to me. this is valid for all but only dynamic arrays, if I get it right...?

Comment: If what you have is a pointer then the assignment copies the reference. For instance an assignment wouldn't copy a class instance. Strings are the exceptions.

Comment: Strings have copy-on-write (COW) mechanism, so they are different from other reference types.

Comment: What I thought was that by defining a variable itself, and setting the length for dynamic types, allocates the memory automatically... I guess I was very wrong. 
Thanks for clarification about this one. The article you gave the link to clarifies a lot.

Comment: @LURD - What matters here is that the strings have "copy" mechanism. COW is the optimization that delays actual copying until needed. Not relevant here ... I think..

Comment: Lots of problems with the code though. Needless duplication. You can do both increasing and decreasing in the same code but switched just on the compare. You need to learn about Boolean. Your swap technique is opaque and obscure. Use a temp. Goto is needless and to be avoided. You sort is an inefficient bubble sort type. `TArray<Integer>` is the dyn array of integer. Also, delphi already comes with sorting functions.

Comment: So, here's your sort function: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TArray.Sort

Comment: Yeah, thank you for the reference link, @DavidHeffernan, but you see, there is actually a reason I use the function above. I have several other things going on during the sorting, since it needs to affect a lot more than just the array that is being sorted. It's actually more than a regular sort function, but I tried to keep it as simple as possible, to expose the actual question/issue I was having - since I didn't know about reference copying only...

Comment: You can do what you need with that function. You just need to use it correctly. The code in the Q is no good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In example 1, you're looping through and assigning the **value** of each element in `a` to the corresponding slot in `b`. You have two separate arrays, with totally separate content.

```
b[i] := a[i];
```

So sorting works on each independent array, and things work as you intend. You can verify this by setting them to different values and then inspecting the elements to confirm they're in fact different:

```
a[0] := 1;
b[i] := 2;   // Inspecting shows a[0] <> b[0].
```

In example 2, you're setting `b` to point to `a`, which means that accessing `b[1]` is actually accessing the same memory location as `a[1]`. You only have one array (`a`), with two references to it (`a` and `b`). Sorting is actually working on a single array, so all you're doing is first sorting the array in ascending order and then resorting the same array (through the second reference) in descending order, and you don't get the results you expect.

You can confirm this by again setting them to different values and then inspecting the elements, but this time they'll be the same value:

```
b := a;
a[0] := 1;
b[0] := 2;      // Both a[0] and b[0] now contain the value 2.
```